# Get all installations using parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I try to get all the installations in my Installations table in parse using Android.
I wrote a query but since this table is not a costum table this row didn't work for me:

```
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query3 = new ParseQuery<ParseInstallation>("Installation");
```

so I read about it and found this:

```
  ParseQuery query3 = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query3.setLimit(1000);
    query3.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseInstallation>() {

        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseInstallation> objects2, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated
            // method stub
            if (e == null) {
```

but its not working either.

Comment: "It's not working" is a very poor problem description. [ask]

Comment: The done method isn't activate.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to list all the records in the Installation table due to Parse security rules. It is very clear in the [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#security-security-edge-cases) that `find` queries will not return all the records in the `Installation` table unless master key is used. You are only allowed to get your own Installation record if the ACL permits that:

> Get requests on installations follow ACLs normally. Find requests,
>   however, return the installation making the request, and only that
>   installation, no matter what ACL is defined on that installation.